# Cannot resolve symbol 'annotation' in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, androidx

i'm using the new AndroidX in my project, and i need to use Nulllable (@Nullable) in my code, but, when i try "import android.support.annotation.Nullable;", this command return to me: "Cannot resolve symbol 'annotation' ".

This i my build.gradle in module level:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    // Implementação da autenticação com o servirdor firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    //Implementação da parte visual do Firebase
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.1.0'
    // Implementação de imagens arrendodas
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    // Autenticação geral com o servirdor do Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    // Autenticação integrada ao google play services
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0' // Integração ao Google Análises
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    // Integração ao sistema de notifação
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    // Integração com o banco de dados
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    // Integração ao sistema de autenticação de usuário
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't mix *android support* and *androidx*.

For androidx, use **androidx.annotation.Nullable**

Comment: When i pressed "alt+enter" the auto import happened (import android.support.annotation.Nullable), can be a "bug" with Android Studio version?

Comment: Regarding your gradle file, I don't why Studio import the support package... Sounds lie a little bug, yes. Try to restart Studio maybe

Comment: I made a "Clean Project" and the imports was correct now, i must be have forgotten to clean project.

Answer (score 0):

as I have found the information on [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/package-summary)
you need to migrate to Androidx. To find the AndroidX class that maps to this deprecated class, see the AndroidX support library on [Class Mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings)

Therefore, replace `android.support.annotation.Nullable` with `androidx.annotation.Nullable`.